# Update em duas tabelas usando php mysql parou de funcionar

Tags: php, sql-update

Pessoal estou com problemas em executar o update em duas tabelas... 
Funcionava até pouco tempo, porém atualizou o XAMMP que utilizo para teste e simplesmente parou!
Existe nova forma de executar o update?

```
<?php

// RECEBENDO OS DADOS PREENCHIDOS DO FORMULÁRIO DE BUSCA!
$id = isset($_GET['id']) ? $_GET['id'] : '';

include("conecta.php");

//Query que realiza o update na tabela entsaida    
$query = "UPDATE `entsaida` SET `saida`= NOW() WHERE id='$id'";

//Query que realiza update no status da senha selecionada 
$query2 = "UPDATE `senhas` SET `status`='0' WHERE id = '$id'"; 

mysqli_query($conn,$query);
mysqli_query($conn,$query2);


//script para voltar a página após update nas tabelas
echo"<script type='text/javascript'>";
echo "alert('Saída cadastrada com sucesso!');";
echo "javascript:window.location='saida.php';";
echo "</script>";

?>
```

Antes de mais nada a conexão está ok... update na primeira tabela é efetuado, na segunda não.
Como procedo?
Obrigado.

Comment: Veja se assim retorna algum erro: `mysqli_query($conn,$query2) or die(mysqli_error($conn));`

Comment: Não contém erro... vai normal. porém não faz o update na segunda query2

Comment: O id passado não existe. Tentou dar um `echo $query2;` e testar direto no banco? pra ter certeza se acontece ou não o update.

Comment: o ID existe...  olha a saída  UPDATE `entsaida` SET `saida`= NOW() WHERE id='15'

Comment: diretamente no banco funciona... e funcionava o update nas duas tabelas até ontem antes da atualização do xammp... experimentei em outras 3 maquinas e ocorre o mesmo problema. então imaginei que o erro fosse nessa parte.

Comment: Tecnicamente, penso eu que não existe erro e que o problema seja no xammp provavelmente!

Comment: Bom estou resolvendo de outra maneira... vou colocar dois id diferentes... assim se continuar o erro eu desisto!

Comment: resolvido utilizando o id da senha e não o id do cadastro da entrada.... separei e ficou dois                                                          
        $id = isset($_GET['id']) ? $_GET['id'] : '';     
        $idsenha = isset($_GET['senha']) ? $_GET['senha'] : '';

Comment: obrigado pela ajuda assim mesmo!